# Product amounts do not submit when there is a drop down menu

Tags: html, paypal

We have a couple of products and the first one has a drop down menu associated with it.

Somehow this dropdown menu prevents the submission of the data from the second product. Please see http://www.kalikalos.com/eStore/book_test.html

What do we need to do to make this work?

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@kalikalos.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Facilitator_in_residence" />

<table width="90%" border="1" align="center">  
<tr><th>&nbsp;&nbsp;FIR PROGRAMME</th><th align="center"> FACILITATOR IN RESIDENCE</th><th width="80" align="center">N<sup>o</sup>. &nbsp;of Places</th><th width="70">Standard FIR <font color="#FF0000">&euro;165</font></th><th width="80" align="center">Early Bird FIR <font color="#FF0000">&euro;122.50</font></th><th width="80" align="center">Leisure FIR <small>(Less staff commitment)</small> <font color="#FF0000">&euro;235</font></th><th width="60" align="center">Artist, Scientist<br />or Writer in Residence <font color="#FF0000">&euro;295</font></th></tr>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFF66"><th><b><i><big>Facilitator-in-Residence</big></i></b> <br /><br /> from June through September &nbsp;

<table align="center">
<tr><td>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Start_Date" /></td>
<td>
<select name="os0">
<option value="~~-">Select start date </option>
<option value="29May">29 May </option>
<option value="26June">26 June </option>
<option value="17July">17 July </option>
<option value="28Aug">28 Aug </option>
<option value="4Sept">4 Sept
</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

</table>  
</th>

<td><img src="thumbs/yoga_in_roundhouse.jpg" width="115" height="92" alt="" align="left" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="3" name="quantity" /></td>
<td title="165"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="165" checked="checked" />
</label></td>
<td title="122.50"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="122.50" />
</label></td>

<td title="235.00"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="235.00" />
</label></td>

<td title="295.00"><label>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="295.00" />
</label></td>
</tr>

<!-- Accommodations line -->

<tr bgcolor="#CCFF99">
<th align="center"><h3>Select Your Accommodation</h3> </th>

<td><img src="thumbs/RoomG_martiou.jpg" width="100" height="75" alt="" align="right" />&nbsp;</td>

<td align="center"><small><b>Please re-enter N<sup>o</sup>. of Places</b></small><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="3" name="quantity_1" /></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFF99"><small>Standard retreat price incldues triple or quad  accomodation</small><br /> <label>

<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="0" checked="checked" />
</label></td>

<td title="&euro;75/person"><label>Twin (&euro;75)

<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="75" />
</label></td>

<td title="&euro;150"><label>Single (&euro;150)
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="150" />
</label></td>

<td title="&euro;.02"><label>Request Tent
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value=".02" />
</label></td>    </tr> 
</table>
<br />


<center>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Accommodation" />

<input type="image" src="../eStore/paynow.jpg" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
</center>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to help you out here but to be quite honest with you, your code is pretty hard to read. I would suggest that before you work on trouble shooting this issue, you start by re doing this page using divs and css styling instead of tables. Not only are tables often ugly on the user side of things, the table that you're using here doesn't make very much sense (You have what appears to be a table heading that is only relevant to your first row. Very confusing for the user), and it makes it hard for others to read and troubleshoot your code. I'm sorry that this isn't the most helpful advice for you right now, but it's going to take me some time to read through the mess of tables you've got here and figure out where your problem is.

I've been struggling to piece together exactly what all of the options on this form are for, but it looks to me like you have options regarding the type of service a user would like to purchase, as well as their desired program.

Personally what I would do here is break this into two, separate sections. Use

```
<div class="form-section">
    <h2>Form Section Heading</h2>
    [contents of section of form here]
</div>
```

to break your form into two logical, distinct components. I would also suggest that you consider removing the redundant quantity field as making a user enter that same number twice is poor user experience.

You will find that the "placeholder" attribute in a text field or text area tag will allow you to insert placeholder text that tells the user what the field is for without taking up additional screen real estate. Use text in line with your radio buttons to tell the user what those do (this is not the best design practice, but it's a big step forward from this web of table cell and rows and headers you have here).

You'll also want to read up a bit on CSS to learn how to style html elements with a stylesheet instead of inline.

Comment: Okay, I will work on the code per your suggestions and re=post it so it is easier to read and fathom. Thanks!